# Naive Bayes Classifier in SAS

Tags: sas, naivebayes

I am attempting to classify a dataset based on heart diease using the naive bayes classifier on sas.The dataset i am using can be found on kaggle using https://www.kaggle.com/johnsmith88/heart-disease-dataset. The code I am using is below.

```
data heart_train;
 set heart_train;
 if target="0" then class_diease="2";
 if target="1" then class_diease="1";
run;


%nb( train=heart_train, score=heart_test, 
 nclass=2,
target=class_diease, inputs=age sex cp trestbps chol 
fbs restecg thalach exang oldpeak slope ca thal) 
%end;
```

when i run this code i get alot of errors such as

ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types.
ERROR: Column sex could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name B.
ERROR: Column sex could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name B.
ERROR: WHERE clause operator requires compatible variables.

can anyone tell me why my code isnt working?

Comment: No one can offer much help with this because your code is calling a macro called NB that we can't see. Just based on the error message, you can see that the macro is trying to find the variable SEX on some data set where it doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist in your HEART_TRAIN data set, then you need to either create it, or remove it from the list of variables in the INPUTS parameter.

Comment: Another possible issue is that, as the data set from Kaggle is CSV, you may need to convert some of the columns to be numeric. It seems odd that you create the CLASS_DISEASE column as a character column, when it contains values "1" and "2". It's possible that the NB macro expects the TARGET variable to be numeric, but we can't be sure.

Comment: All the columns are numeric values , and the columns i have input re all in the dataframe

Comment: The code shows that TARGET and CLASS_DIEASE (typo, missing 'S'?) are character variables, so it's not true that they're all numeric. A character variable with a value of "2" is still a character variable in SAS.